# SQL Server stored procedure only works with locally re-declared variables; not variables passed to the procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, asp-classic

**I have edited my SQL code blocks to more accurately show what is going on**

Say I have a simple stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [DBO].[FOO]
    (@VARIABLE VARCHAR(500))
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT AVG(BAR) 
    FROM MYTABLE 
    WHERE THING = @VARIABLE AND RTRIM(LTRIM(THING)) <> ''
END
```

When I call this stored procedure from my classic ASP page; which in this case would be with:

```
Set foo = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
curCmd = "Foo 'MYVARIABLE'"
foo.Open curCmd, connectionString
```

I get this error (on the same line as the page opens the foo object):

> Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

If I call the stored procedure manually in the terminal (IDE?); then it works fine.

Also if I recreate the stored procedure as the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [DBO].[FOO]
    (@VARIABLE VARCHAR(500))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @VARIABLE2 VARCHAR(500) = @VARIABLE

    SELECT AVG(BAR) 
    FROM MYTABLE 
    WHERE THING = @VARIABLE2 AND RTRIM(LTRIM(THING)) <> ''
END
```

Then the stored procedure runs fine.

I have tried dropping and recreating the stored procedure (without using the re-declaration trick), but it does not fix the issue.

*As an aside; there is validation on the data being inserted into the table to ensure that only numbers (integers) are being entered for the THING field. The THING field can also be blank; hence the where clause.

I basically have two questions:

1. Why does re-declaring the same variable type with the same data fix the issue?
2. Is there a way I can fix my problem without using this silly "re-declaration" trick?

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: What is the data type of your `THING`?

Comment: It is a VARCHAR(50). I have updated my question to be closer to what I really have (business related work so I can't copy the actual code; sorry).

Comment: Rather than using just the `RecordSet` object, could you use a `Command` object where you explicitly pass the stored proc name (only) as the `CommandText`, set the `CommandType` appropriately and set the parameters via the parameters collection?

Comment: I just tried using a Command object with appropriate parameters passed, and had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get the same error if you use `begin`/`end`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [DBO].[FOO] (
    @VARIABLE VARCHAR(500)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @VARIABLE2 VARCHAR(500) = @VARIABLE;
    SELECT AVG(BAR) FROM MYTABLE WHERE THING = @VARIABLE2;
END;
```

Then, both statements will be part of the stored procedure body and you can work on fixing the data so it will work.

Comment: My apologies; I have the begin and end included, but I forgot to include them in the question I posted. Also to be clear I know the data works; since the procedure can be called successfully if I do so manually.